# why i have Invalid Syntax in pygame.draw?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from player import Player
import math
from map import *

pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH , HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    player.movement()
    sc.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.circle(sc , GREEN , (int(player.x) ,(int(player.y)), 12 )
    pygame.draw.line(sc, GREEN, player.pos, (player.x + WIDTH * math.cos(player.angle),
                                             player.y + WIDTH * math.sin(player.angle)))
    for x,y in world_map:
        pygame.draw.rect(sc , DARKGRAY , (x , y , TILE , TILE),2)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

---

```
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/game3d.py", line 20
    pygame.draw.line(sc, GREEN, player.pos, (player.x + WIDTH * math.cos(player.angle),
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image]

Comment: @Carcigenicate there's actually an extra one inside the tuple with the `int` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra parentheses on line 19

```
pygame.draw.circle(sc , GREEN , (int(player.x) ,(int(player.y)), 12 )
```

should be

```
pygame.draw.circle(sc , GREEN , (int(player.x) , int(player.y)), 12 )
```